# Make ImageView to look the same on different devices

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView that has the following properties,

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
```

So, aparently 100dp doesn't look the same on different devices.
How can I make the ImageView to look the same on tablet as it looks on phone? using just 1 layout

[phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVLRC.png)

[tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhTbj.png)

Comment: Define same. You mean the same size, or the same scale?

Comment: Switch `dp` to `px`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ConstraintLayout`'s `layout_constraintGuide_percent` attribute so that the size is always relative to the screen width and height.

See [the example in the docs of the (deprecated) `PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) on how to use a `ConstraintLayout` to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've defined your `ImageView` to be the size of the screen, minus some margins. So on small screens it will be really small, and on large screens it will be really large.

You'd be better off simply defining how large you want it to be directly. Your "phone" screenshot looks like you're probably working with a 320dp wide screen, so you could just write this instead:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
```

Now your image view will always be ~2.5cm wide/tall on every screen, centered horizontally, and ~2cm from the top edge of the screen.